# Javamail logging to service with FROM value

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I'm using Javamail in my mailing service. This is my code:

```
   public static void send( final String username, final String password, String recipientEmail, String ccEmail, String title, String message,
                         String from, String host, String port )
    throws AddressException, MessagingException
{
    Session session;

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty( "mail.smtps.host", host );
    props.setProperty( "mail.smtp.port", port );

    session = Session.getInstance( props, null );

    // -- Create a new message --
    final MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage( session );

    // -- Set the FROM and TO fields --
    msg.setFrom( new InternetAddress( username ) );
    msg.setRecipients( Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse( recipientEmail, false ) );

    if ( ccEmail.length() > 0 )
    {
        msg.setRecipients( Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse( ccEmail, false ) );
    }

    msg.setSubject( title, "utf-8" );
    msg.setFrom( new InternetAddress( from ) );
    msg.setText( message, "utf-8" );
    msg.setSentDate( new Date() );

    SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport( "smtps" );

    t.connect( host, username, password );
    t.sendMessage( msg, msg.getAllRecipients() );
    t.close();
}
```

I call this method giving e.g
- username: mailtest
- from: My Super Company  <- this is my domain
- host: mail.host.com <- this is my mail provider

and javamail is trying to log in to my service as **mailtest@mysupercompany.com** and it fails. When I give from e.g: **test@mysupercompany.com** it works fine.

I've checked the logs in console and it says that user mailtest@mysupercompany.com does not exist. It's like javamail would try to login with mailtest@mysupercompany.com, but it should use only my username **mailtest**.

Why it is using from when it's the same as username?

Answer (score 0):

It should be using whatever you pass in as username.  Make sure it's what you expect; print it out before the connect call.

Add session.setDebug(true).  What does the debug output show?

Comment: I did check my login, it is correct when I use client in web browser. Login: mailtest, but when I try to do it with java and I'm passing also a From value like My Company <mailtest@mail.host.com> it uses the from value.

Comment: I will add session.setDebug(true) and response when I get message (I'm not currently at home). Can u tell me where the output will be given? Eclipse console?